# Deleting objects in RealmResults somehow triggers a insertion change listener

Tags: android, realm

I'm running a JobService every x hours to cleanup duplicates (objects created within 5 seconds).
First I load every `MyContainer` (sorted or not makes no difference for triggering insertions) and subsequently every object with matching fields and a timestamp within 5secs. Found objects are deleted

```
//Simplified for this question

public static void doCleanUp(Context context) {
    Realm realm = context.mRealm;

    realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {

        RealmResults<MyContainer> allContainer = realm1.where(MyContainer.class)
                .findAllSorted("timestamp", Sort.ASCENDING);

        // implicit snapshot
        for (MyContainer item : allContainer) {
            if (item.isValid()) {
                RealmResults<MyContainer> toDelete = realm1.where(MyContainer.class)
                    .notEqualTo("rowId", item.getRowId())
                    .equalTo("name", item.getName())
                    .equalTo("path", item.getPath())
                    .lessThan("timestamp", item.getTimestamp() + 5000)
                    .findAll();

                if (toDelete.size() > 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "RealmCleanupJobService: deleteing objects " + toDelete.size());
                    toDelete.deleteAllFromRealm();
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```

In another service a changeListener is listening, however it is only reacting on insertions:

```
private void setupRealmCollectionListener() {

    mThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    mAllContainer = getRealm().where(MyContainer.class).findAllSorted("timestamp", Sort.DESCENDING);
    mAllContainer.addChangeListener((myContainers, changeSet) -> {
        if (changeSet == null) return;

        OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range[] insertions = changeSet.getInsertionRanges();
        for (OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range range : insertions) {
            for (int i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
                MyContainer ac = getRealm().copyFromRealm(myContainers.get(range.startIndex + i));
                mThreadPool.execute(() -> {
                    // ...
                });
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Deletion works as expected. However, some insertions appear:

[image: Android Studio Image]

How do i combat this and why insertions are appearing? I thought about some workarounds, like removing and readding the listener.

- Tested with Realm 3.7.2 and 3.5.0
- Android Studio 3.0 Beta 5
- CompileSdk 26, Target 25

Comment: Can you guarantee that you are NOT inserting anything into the Realm from anywhere?

Comment: No insertions from anywhere else. The inserted objects also are not new, they are old objects.

Comment: that's strange, I am also using latest realm and doing a lot of similar operations, and everything works fine!

Comment: @SarthakMittal Can you please make a sample project to reproduce this issue? if you can, please fire a bug in https://github.com/realm/realm-java . this sounds like a bug.

Comment: @beeender sure! most of the code is already written, as I filed an issue some time ago(which wasn't really a bug).

Comment: @AsterixR check this sample: https://github.com/SarthakM9/RealmTest 
your issue isn't reproducible!

Comment: @AsterixR I mentioned wrong people in the comments before ... Could you please make a sample project to show the problem? SartakMittal made one here https://github.com/SarthakM9/RealmTest and it works fine.